# 'Random' error 4605 when copy/pasting multiple cells from Excel into Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, clipboard

I am working to automate paper documents that would otherwise need to be handwritten. I have a Word template with bookmarks, which are then located and pasted to using the vba code from excel. My problem is that randomly, I will get error 4605 nothing in clipboard or bad format. If I rerun the code, it will often run fine. I believe that the issue is from the clipboard being overfilled or something, so I added a few lines I found online to clear the clipboard each iteration and before starting the loop. Error still appears and I am thinking there could be other issues with my code, this is my first time using VBA.

```
Sub CreateWordDoc()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim SaveAsName As String
    Dim xAutoWrapper As Object
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set xAutoWrapper = New DataObject
    
    With wdApp
    '.Visible = True
    '.Activate
    
    '.Documents.Add "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Rain Delay Letter Template Rev 10.dotx"
    ccc
    For x = 7 To 50
        If Range("V" & x).Value <> "N/A" Then
        .Documents.Add "C:\Users\SPringle\Desktop\Rain Delay Letter Template Rev 10.dotx"
        Range("D1").Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "LetterDate"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       
        Range("Y" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Address"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Debug.Print Err.Number
        Range("X" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Client"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Range("W" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Contact"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        xAutoWrapper.SetText Range("Z" & x).Text
        xAutoWrapper.PutInClipboard
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "LastName"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Range("U" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Dates"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range("V" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Amounts"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Range("B" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "ProjectName"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Range("D" & x).Copy
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "PM"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Range("AA" & x).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Signature"
        .Selection.Paste
        
        SaveAsName = Environ("UserProfile") _
        & "\Desktop\RainLetters\Rain Delay - " _
        & Range("B" & x).Value & " " & Range("I1").Value & ".docx"
        
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveAsName
        .ActiveDocument.Close
        End If
        ccc
        Next x
End With
MsgBox ("Letters are complete!")
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function

Sub ccc()
    Call ClearClipboard
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the bookmark text directly from the range, as taller_Excelhome already pointed out.  It's cleaner to wrap that process into a separate sub.

```vb
Sub CreateWordDoc()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document
    Dim SaveAsName As String
    Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'for example
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    wdApp.Visible = True
    
    For x = 7 To 50
        If ws.Range("V" & x).Value <> "N/A" Then
            
            Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Add("C:\Users\SPringle\Desktop\Rain Delay Letter Template Rev 10.dotx")
            doc.SaveAs2 SaveAsName
            
            SetBookmarkText doc, "LetterDate", ws.Range("D1").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "Address", ws.Cells(x, "Y").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "Client", ws.Cells(x, "X").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "Contact", ws.Cells(x, "W").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "LastName", ws.Cells(x, "Z").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "Dates", ws.Cells(x, "U").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "V", ws.Cells(x, "Amounts").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "ProjectName", ws.Cells(x, "B").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "PM", ws.Cells(x, "D").Value
            SetBookmarkText doc, "AA", ws.Cells(x, "Signature").Value
            
            SaveAsName = Environ("UserProfile") _
                    & "\Desktop\RainLetters\Rain Delay - " _
                    & ws.Range("B" & x).Value & " " & ws.Range("I1").Value & ".docx"
            
            doc.Close savechanges:=True
        End If 'V value not N/A
    Next x
    MsgBox ("Letters are complete!")
End Sub

'set the text for a bookmark, preserving the bookmark
Sub SetBookmarkText(doc As Word.Document, bmName As String, v)
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = doc.Bookmarks(bmName).Range  'get the range
    rng.Text = v                           'set the text (note this will delete the bookmark)
    doc.Bookmarks.Add bmName, rng          'recreate bookmark
End Sub
```

Comment: I adapted this to my needs perfectly. Runs much faster now but my only issue is that SetBookmarkText doc, "AA", ws.Cells(x, "Signature").Value cannot be used because the cell is a picture. Is there a way to copy the picture using your method of 'pasting' into word?

Comment: I got it to work with Range("AA" & x).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture
            .Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "Signature"
            .Selection.Paste   but this method is very slow due to the xlPrinter selection

Comment: I think you're stuck with copy/paste if it's not just text content.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy from Excel and paste values into Word. Using `Selection.TypeText` in Word is better. Copying and pasting between applications uses more system resources.

```vb
        .Selection.GoTo wdGoToBookmark, , , "LetterDate"
        .Selection.TypeText Text:=Range("D1").Value
```

The upper code snippet accomplishes the same result as your code.

```vb
        Range("D1").Copy
        .Selection.GoTo wdGoToBookmark, , , "LetterDate"
        .Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```